# Free alternative to QTCreator for QT/C++ development

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, qt-creator

Let me preface this by stating I have vision problems so I have to magnify my screen upwards of 400% minimum to read most things including code - even when I am using a dark theme as I do when I code.

QTCreator has an issue where it moves the view on me with most keystrokes & actions - usually to the top left corner by the project file listing.  I've posed questions to QT Support and even cloned the source for QT Creator looking to see if I could identify a relatively easy fix - to no avail.  So now I'm trying to find a free (as in no financial cost) alternative to QT Creator so I can keep programming using QT Creator in C++.

I've tried Visual Studio Community Edition (2017 and 2019) and had problems getting things to build.  It seemed like I had to rebuild the entire framework libraries for MSVC or else it wouldn't work.  Additionally it seems it finds compilation errors in even the framework source - which doesn't even look wrong to me or I'd try to repair it.

I tried Eclipse (as I'm a Java engineer for my job so I'm familiar with Eclipse for Java and it does not have the problem that QT Creator has.  The QT plugin - when I try to put a simple line of #include  - It claims "QApplication" is unresolved.  I've looked for this and all the answers say about Project->Properties->Paths and Symbols but as of 2019-12 and 2020-03, there are **no** options in settings for paths and symbols unfortunately.

A colleague suggested CLion from JetBrains but unfortunately it appears you have to pay for that.  I have no intention of paying for a compiler or IDE.

Any thoughts on how I can get around this view changing problem or an alternative to QTCreator that doesn't cost money?  If there's a setting in one of the applications I may have missed, suggest it with the version of the appication and I'll look for it and reply if it doesn't exist for whatever reason or accept your answer if it does and fixes the problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with Eclipse but have issues with the plugins and you intend using it for C++ I recommend checking out Cevelop (https://www.cevelop.com/) it's basically Eclipse but only for C++ and has some optimizations.
If that doesn't work for you technically you should be able to use any code editor like VSCode or Atom, but I do not know how well that works with the Qt library.

CLion is free for students but I think that doesn't apply for you.

NetBeans (https://netbeans.org/) is also free and cross-platform.
(https://netbeans.org/kb/74/cnd/qt-applications.html)
It should be possible to use Qt within the IDE.

Comment: I'll check out cevelop - and if that doesn't work I'll check out Netbeans again - I disliked NetBeans for Java but maybe it's the C++ solution I need - we'll see - if one of them works, I'll click the check to accept your answer :)  Thanks!

Comment: It would appear that NetBeans only works with Java, PHP, and HTML/CSS/Javascript.  I wasn't able to find any way to code/build in C++ :-(  As for Cevelop - While it codes in C++ and actually HAS the Paths and Symbols section that Eclipse should have based on all I've read, it doesn't seem to have any way to add the QT module/plugin that my copy of Eclipse does have - and it doesn't show up in the marketplace or "Install New Software".  I'll keep looking I guess - Maybe I can get QT to build somehow with luck in MSVC who knows

Comment: Oh I’m sorry. I’m going to keep an eye open for the tool you’re searching

Comment: Code::Blocks is also a kinda popular IDE. Have you thought about searching a viewing aid extension instead of a new IDE?

Comment: For QT there is nothing like Viewing aid extensions that I have ever been able to find - Yes I have looked for magnification tools but the only thing I have ever found has been the Magnifying glass apps like what I use.  Even Eclipse doesn't have anything - The only thing Eclipse has is that one can increase the font size but it doesn't work for every part of it unfortunately so the magnifying app I use is the best thing for that.